# How to remove the "result" overlays but not the "current position" overlay

Tags: android, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay

I my application there is button "show me",and a spinner to choose radius ,and one button "search" to search results,,
my problem i that when i tap on "show me" it shows the overlay at current location and when i search after choosing radius it shows the results in the map with overlays but my current position overlay removes..because i am using

```
List<Overlay> mapOverlays_results;

mapOverlays_results =mapView.getOverlays();
mapOverlays_results.clear();
```

but if i dont use these above lines and i decrease the radius old results also seen in the map..

How to remove the result overlays but not the current position overlay..
How to solve this..?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've got more than one overlay (I'm guessing two), then instead of mapOverlays_results.clear(), you should try mapOverlays_results.remove(int arg), where arg will be the index of the overlay that isn't your position.

Comment: i tried this :if(overlayItem != null)
   {
   mapView.getOverlays().remove(overlayItem);
   overlayItem =null; }     but it is not working...not removing a single overlay...i m showing near about 25 overlays..n want to remove those but not the current position overlay..

Comment: hey..was passing the wrong argument...mapOverlays_results.remove(int arg)..working perfectly..:)